# macos - ionic cordova build android: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn EACCES

Tags: android, macos, cordova, ionic-framework, spawn

I am trying to build an android application on ionic but im getting this error:

```
(node:68392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn EACCES
    at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:502:9)
    at Object.exports.spawn 

(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:134:31) at runScriptViaChildProcessSpawn
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:225:23) at runScript
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:166:16) at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:132:20 at _fulfilled 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54) at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30) at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)

(node:68392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:68392) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Same here. It's a very recent problem. I downgraded some dependencies, but it hasn't fixed the problem.